# Combine multiple categorical columns into one, when each row has only one non-NaN value, in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categorical

I have

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df = pd.DataFrame({"x": ["red", "blue", np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, ],
                   "y": [np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'cold', 'warm', np.nan, np.nan, ],
                   "z": [np.nan, np.nan,  np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, 'charm', 'strange'],
                  }).astype("category")
```

giving

```
     x     y        z
0   red   NaN      NaN
1  blue   NaN      NaN
2   NaN   NaN      NaN
3   NaN  cold      NaN
4   NaN  warm      NaN
5   NaN   NaN    charm
6   NaN   NaN  strange
```

I would like to add a new categorical column with unordered values red,blue,hot,cold,warm, charm, strange, filled in appropriately. I have many such columns, not just three.

Some possiblities:

- `astype(str)` and concatenating and then re-creating a categorical
- creating a new categorical type using `union_categoricals` and then cast each column to that type? and then serially `fillna()` them?

I can't make those or anything else work.

Notes:
using `.astype(pd.CategoricalDtype(ordered=True))` in place of `.astype("category")` in defining `df` also works with the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**New Solution**

For the purpose of using for a large datasets, the following solution may be more efficient:

```
def my_fun(x):
    m = ~ pd.isnull(x)
    if m.any():
        return x[m]
    else:
        return np.nan

df['new'] = np.apply_along_axis(my_fun, 1, df.to_numpy())

      x     y        z      new
0   red   NaN      NaN      red
1  blue   NaN      NaN     blue
2   NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN
3   NaN  cold      NaN     cold
4   NaN  warm      NaN     warm
5   NaN   NaN    charm    charm
6   NaN   NaN  strange  strange
```

**Edited answer**

As specified by the OP, in case there are rows where all values are `np.NaN` we could try the following solution:

```
df['new_col'] = df.dropna(how='all').apply(lambda x: x.loc[x.first_valid_index()], axis=1)
df['new_col'] = pd.Categorical(df.new_col)
df

      x     y        z  new_col
0   red   NaN      NaN      red
1  blue   NaN      NaN     blue
2   NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN
3   NaN  cold      NaN     cold
4   NaN  warm      NaN     warm
5   NaN   NaN    charm    charm
6   NaN   NaN  strange  strange
```

Comment: Wow!  But the new column should be categorical.

Comment: Yes I just modified. In case you have rows where all values are np.NaN.

Comment: I found a problem in my real data: I get a "KeyError: None" error due to there being an all-NaN row. I've now modified the example by changing "hot" to np.nan.  Your answer now needs a .dropna(how='all') after `df.` to work (unless you've another idea).   Thank you!!!

Comment: Btw, this method is extremely slow for my data (2496520 rows x 156 columns). I do wonder whether there is something faster.

Comment: @CPBL I posted a new solution. Could you please try this one and let me know how it works on your data set?

Comment: Thank you very much. This made me time it, and actually, it wasn't taking that long for one iteration (my code needs several): your first one-line code took 152 seconds. The new one takes 96 seconds.  These are both fast enough, actually, and your first one is twice as elegant. Thanks!!

Comment: That's my pleasure. I was also curious about the run time of the new one on a huge data set but glad it helped :)

Answer (score 1):

Try `ffill()`

```
df['col'] = df.ffill(axis=1).iloc[:,-1].astype('category')
```

or `stack()` with `groupby()`

```
df['col'] = df.stack().groupby(level=0).first().astype('category')
```

Output:

```
      x     y        z      col
0   red   NaN      NaN      red
1  blue   NaN      NaN     blue
2   NaN   NaN      NaN      NaN
3   NaN  cold      NaN     cold
4   NaN  warm      NaN     warm
5   NaN   NaN    charm    charm
6   NaN   NaN  strange  strange
```

Comment: Thanksl `ffill()` method took 555 seconds, as compared with 96s and 152s for methods in @AnoushiravanR's answer.